# Google vision batch label prediction from Images web URI

Tags: google-vision

I'm trying to use Google vision API to predict labels from Images from web URI(Not Google storage bucket), I can do this for single images using

```
const [result] = await client.labelDetection('https://someimageurl.com/img1.jpg');
```

If I do the same for batch prediction, it is requiring the image uri from google storage bucket.

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid gcs prefix provided in request image.source.image_uri field. 
                  Valid prefixes must start with 'gs://'.
```

The request object for this looks like this, I'm wondering if there is a way to pass actual image URL in the request object instead of storage bucket URI.

```
const imageRequest = {
    image: {
        source: {
            imageUri: "https://someimageurl.com/img1.jpg",
        },
    },
    features: features,
};
```

Edit: As per documentation for imageSource it should support web URI for imageUri and gcsImageUri for Google cloud storage bucket but it doesn't seem to work for me, am I missing something.

Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageRequest#imagesource